# Python - Django add username to QuerySet fields

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-queryset

I have a problem since four days and I hope that anyone can help me.

I have a model class A, which has User as Foreign Key and other attributes:

class A(models.Model):

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User)
....
```

In views.py:

```
objects_as_json = serializers.serialize('json', classA.objects.filter(user_id=2).order_by("-date"))
```

I got this as Response:

```
[{"model": "senApp.classA", "pk": 10, "fields": {"user": 2, "partner": null, "image": 6, "contest": 4, "action": 2, "date": "2016-07-29T09:35:59Z"}}, {"model": "sengApp.classA", "pk": 9, "fields": {"user": 2, "partner": 6, "image": 1, "contest": null, "action": 1, "date": "2016-07-29T09:23:43Z"}}]
```

So my question is, how can i add the username of the user in fields like this:

```
{"model": "senApp.classA", "pk": 10, "fields": {"user": 2, "partner": null, "image": 6, "contest": 4, "action": 2, "date": "2016-07-29T09:35:59Z", "username":}}
```

Thank you very much in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the keyword argument `use_natural_foreign_keys` to `True`:

```
objects_as_json = serializers.serialize(
    'json',
    classA.objects.filter(user_id=2).order_by("-date"),
    use_natural_foreign_keys=True
)
```

Also [see the django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.10/topics/serialization/#serialization-of-natural-keys) how you control what is returned as *natural key*

Comment: Hi, Nils Werner...
I get the following response: 
     {"model": "sengApp.classA", "pk": 10, "fields": {"user": ["test3@bsp.com"], "partner": null, "image": 6, "contest": 4, "action": 2, "date": "2016-07-29T09:35:59Z"}}

but I need the user id too

Comment: As I said, *see the link I also posted*. It is documented there.